# Splitting an expression with lambda into multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, lambda

I have an expression that looks like this, that I am trying to parse, where `someFunction` and `anotherFunc` are two already written functions:

```
someFunction('$Variable', ['$OneVar', 'was', 'an', '$TwoVar'],
    lambda a: anotherFunc(a[1].lower(), a[0].lower()))
```

Here, `a[0]` corresponds to `$OneVar` and `a[1]` corresponds to `$TwoVar`. `.lower()` just makes everything lower case.

Is there a way to split this up into multiple lines (trying to understand things better, and this usually helps)?

I know usually you can do something like:

```
def func1(a):
    anotherFunc(a[1].lower(), a[0].lower())

someFunction('$Variable', ['$OneVar', 'was', 'an', '$TwoVar'], func1)
```

However, I see that here it does not work because `a` contains two arguments and is indexed. Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you would use lambda, why would you not just include the function in `someFunction` and just also pass a as argument?

Comment: I recommend passing another arguments in someFunction() along with func1, and then call it inside

Comment: someFunction() is a pre-written function that is fixed  and can't be changed (too complicated). Do you have any suggestion for the way I described, trying to keep a separate function to call a[1] and a[0]? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, i see. And it works with lambda? Then the other variation should work as well. What error code are you getting?